# 555 Astable Period Incorrect

Tags: 555, timing

I set up an astable 555 timer with the output connected to an LED. C1 = 1000 uF, 16V. R1 = 68000 Ohm. R2 = 33000 Ohm. Vcc = 6.5V. By my calculations, the total period should be roughly 93 seconds. But, when I turned on the circuit, the total period was roughly 520 seconds, high output for 490 seconds and low output for 30. I noticed I hadn't sunk my control pin to ground. I did that and the total period ended up being around 407 seconds, yet the capacitor was charging to 1V and discharging to 0V. I'm very confused as to why this happened. Both the timing and the voltages are nowhere near what they should be. What can I do to fix this? Or at least test to move forward?

Comment: Your question is deliberately leaving information out and that will earn it downvotes and complaints. *Both the timing and the voltages are nowhere near what they should be* - well, what should they be or does every reader have to work them out for themselves?

Comment: *C1 = 1000 uF* That sets of my alarm bells already ! These capacitors do not have accurate values, it could easily be 1500 uF instead of 1000 uF. These capacitors can have high leakage currents. You simply should not attempt to make a long timing using a 555. Instead use a 4060 or a micro controller. These use a fast running oscillator and then a counter to make the long time. That scheme is much more reliable and predictable.

Comment: @FakeMoustache or simply use a counter IC for the low frequencies

Comment: Closing due to handwaving instead of schematic.

Answer (score 2):

The RC equation for the 555, or for any circuit, doesn't work for huge values of R or C. Other circuit properties become a factor, such as the natural leakage of the massive 1000 uF capacitor.

Unless you're modulating the 555 waveform, which you're not apparently, the control voltage (pin 5) is normally left floating or with a 100 nF decoupling capacitor on it. You mention grounding it, which is not to be done. (Unless you meant a different pin...?)

Look at using a faster oscillator and more accurate oscillator, then dividing its frequency down to much slower. The CD4060 contains an oscillator, with frequency set by an external RC, and a 14-bit binary divider. Details of calculating the RC values are in the CD4060 datasheet. Use the lowest stage of division as an output and run the oscillator as close to 176.17 Hz as you can. Use an adjustable resistor in series with the fixed resistor of the RC to let you fine tune the frequency during testing. You can observe the frequency on a lower stage of division and get that accurate, to save you waiting for 93 seconds at a time during calibration.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not you can still procure a part called a CD4536 that is a very nice part to get long delays. I've used these in the past by coaxing the osc/clk pins to work with a 32.768kHz crystal. With selectable output up to 24 divider stages you can get delays of up to 2^^9 seconds!!.

The output monostable can be used generate a suitable working pulse off the selected divider stage output.